# CheckBox Issue in IE6

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-6, checkbox

I am dynamically generating checkboxes for a popup window (displayed using AJAX) using javascript and on a button click I also need to call a function that checks all the check boxes before the popup is rendered.

All pages in use are JSPs and the popup is also included using the  tag so it is generated already when the parent page gets loaded.

The problem is that I'm able to check all the custom generated checkboxes using the same function in IE7 and IE8. But it does not work for IE6.

I'm using something like:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
     document.getElementById('chk'+i).checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Please wrap your code in a code block (the 1010101 icon at the top of the editor) since it can't be seen at the moment

Answer (score 1):

That code ought to work fine, even in IE6 (which, lets be honest, is a really awful browser).

However, if you have inserted those checkboxes into the page dynamically, IE6 has a known issue with dynamically added checkboxes, where it doesn't respect the `.checked` property.

See this page for a few possible solutions: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/799167-browser-quirk-dynamically-appended-checked-checkbox-does-not-appear-checked-ie

Hope that helps. :-)

(But my solution is: Don't support IE6. Honestly, it's usage is down to a few percent now and getting lower, so unless it's more well used by your particular demographic, just cut your losses and drop it; the remaining users will upgrade soon enough.  ;-))

Comment: Thanks Spudley... Please give me the link for the page you are talking about. I didn't find it in your answer...

Comment: agh! I don't know what happened there!  :-o  added the link for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to sound like a 'use jQuery' pat answer, if you were to do this with a library like jQuery, any IE6 inconsistencies would probably be nicely abstracted away.

Comment: hmmm depends what you mean by "abstracted away". In some cases it's just "hidden by forcing you to use a workaround". But I see your point :)

Comment: thanks for the answer... But the code is working fine in IE7 and IE8 so I'll just need to change a pretty long piece of code for IE6 which I am starting to completely loathe by the way..... :P